# How to show error messages in rails devise plugin for unauthorized page requests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise

I am working in a Ruby on Rails project which has implemented authentication mechanism using Devise plugin. I am new to this plugin as well as Ruby. So having a difficulty in fixing a problem in authentications. The problem is, according to current implementation, if a user tries to go access a page in the application without signing in, it redirects the user to Sign In page by saying that he or she should be signed in or signed up before accessing that page. That's correct. That is the implementation that I need. But what happens is, even if a user directly go to the Login page, this error message is shown. That is not required. Because if a user directly accessing Login page, no point of giving an error message.
Any help will be appreciated.
Thank You.

Comment: /users/sign_in wont show any error message

Comment: That is the current url im using, but it shows the error message.

Comment: Is there a way that I can know user has requested an unauthorized page and because of that he or she is redirected to Login page? Then I can catch it and write my logic to show the error messages in Login page.

Comment: @viktortron No sir, it did not. But that is because I do not have much idea on devise plugin. I found a workaround for that. Anyway thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call devise `authenticate_user!` where you shouldn't and you do not use `require_no_authentication`

You must make sure this before filter is called in your sessions controller

```
prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create ]
```

these are taken care of in devise's default controllers (e.g, Devise::SessionsController), are you using them?